# Convert between an org-mode table and a table.el table without user interaction

Tags: emacs, elisp

I convert org-mode table to table.el table. For that I select the table:

```
| Option      | Type | Value | Descr        |
| -[no]h      | bool | yes   | Print        |
| -[no]versio | bool | no    | Print        |
| -nice       | int  | 0     | Set t        |
| -[no]v      | bool | no    | Be lo        |
| -time       | real | -1    | Take         |
| -[no]rmvsbd | bool | yes   | Removvirtual |
| sites       |      |       |              |
| -maxwarn    | int  | 0     | Numbe        |
| procenerate |      |       |              |
| unsta       |      |       |              |
| -[no]zero   | bool | no    | Set pthout   |
| defau error |      |       |              |
| -[no]renum  | bool | yes   | Renum        |
| atomty      |      |       |              |
```

and press `C-c ~`. `org-mode` then asks me

```
Convert table to table.el table? (y or n)
```

How do I answer `y` programmically? I read the docs of that defun -- there's not way to do it with prefix arg.

Similar functionality in bash:

```
echo y | script-which-asks-y-or-n
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-c ~` calls the command `org-table-create-with-table.el`, which provides a bunch of wrappers around calling `org-table-convert`. If you want to use this function when you know you are already in an org-mode table, you don't need the wrappers, you just need the two (and probably only one) commands: `org-table-align` and `org-table-convert`.

So if you're doing this interactively, you can just call `M-x org-table-convert` and you're done. This assumes the table is already aligned. You can do this by hand by tabbing from one cell to the next, which triggers table alignment. Or you can do it with a small function:

```
(defun my-convert-tables ()
"No questions asked, just convert the table"
  (interactive)
  (org-table-align)
  (org-table-convert))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this programmatically as follows. You would replace the function name test1 with org-table-create-with-table.el in your defadvice functions that would be otherwise the same as those below.

Using defadvice to run some code before and after the function, we can save the function bound to the symbol y-or-n-p to a global variable and rebind it to a function that simply returns true. After the function we then restore the original functionality.

```
(setq save-y-or-n-p nil)

(defadvice test1 (around always-yes) 
  (fset 'save-y-or-n-p (symbol-function 'y-or-n-p)) 
  (fset 'y-or-n-p (lambda (s) t)) 
  ad-do-it 
  (fset 'y-or-n-p (symbol-function 'save-y-or-n-p)))

 (defun test1 ()
  (interactive)
  (if (y-or-n-p "Happy? ")
      (insert "Happy day")
    (insert "Unhappy day")))
```

Comment: Should savedf be save-y-or-n-p in your example?

Comment: Also there should be no quote at `(setq save-y-or-n-p nil)`. This is the nicest example of defadvice. Should be included in all text books.

Comment: You could also do this as a single around advice, instead of two separate advices: (defadvice test1 (around always-yes)
  (fset 'save-y-or-n-p (symbol-function 'y-or-n-p))
  (fset 'y-or-n-p (lambda (s) t))
  ad-do-it
  (fset 'y-or-n-p (symbol-function 'save-y-or-n-p)))

Comment: Thanks Adobe, fixed that. Tyler, yes that's neater, I've made that change too.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought to use advice here, that's pretty neat!